# How do I make this command display how many users the bot is serving?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that displays how many users the bot is serving as of now. I have this so far but whenever I use the command it just says '1'. I would like to know if there is any alternative way to do this.

```
@client.command()
async def memberserved(ctx):
    members_set = set()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            members_set.add(member)
    members = len(members_set)
    membersserved = members
    emb = discord.Embed(title="This bot is serving:",description=f"{membersserved} Members",color=discord.Color((0xffff00)))
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `intents.members` are enabled, if it still doesn't work you can try with the following:

```py
members = []

for guild in bot.guilds:
    members.extend(guild.members)

members_set = set(members)
members_served = len(members_set)
```

To enable the intents in your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)
```

Reference:

- [A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Comment: I still get the same response from the bot where it just says 1. I've enabled intents and everything

Comment: that's weird, tried the same and works for me, any errors?

Comment: did you also enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)?

Comment: I've enabled it on discord developer portal but how do I enable it in my code?

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks, your amazing!!!